# Could not be found for reporter influxdb

Tags: java, apache-flink

I used flink 1.11 but task manager couldn't find org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporterFactory

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.ReporterSetup               [] - The reporter factory (org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporterFactory) could not be found for reporter influxdb. Available factories: [org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.slf4j.Slf4jReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporterFactory].
```

metrics-influx exists in plugins folder!

```
metrics.reporter.influxdb.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporterFactory
metrics.reporter.influxdb.host: localhost
metrics.reporter.influxdb.port: 8086
metrics.reporter.influxdb.db: flink
metrics.reporter.influxdb.username: flink-metrics
metrics.reporter.influxdb.password: qwerty
metrics.reporter.influxdb.retentionPolicy: one_hour
metrics.reporter.influxdb.consistency: ANY
metrics.reporter.influxdb.connectTimeout: 60000
metrics.reporter.influxdb.writeTimeout: 60000
metrics.reporter.influxdb.interval: 60 SECONDS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a known bug in Flink 1.11.0: see [FLINK-18573](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18573).

This will be fixed in 1.11.1. RC1 is open for voting now; see http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/VOTE-Release-1-11-1-release-candidate-1-td43200.html if you want to participate in testing.